# Device Admin API sample: works fine on emulator NoSuchMethod error on Device

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app to disable camera, I was trying Device Admin sample from the SDK , it worked fine on emulator but on device , app force closes on item click and shows NoSuchmethod error.

Code Snippet

```
 public static class AdminSampleFragment extends PreferenceFragment
        implements OnPreferenceChangeListener, OnPreferenceClickListener{

    // Useful instance variables
    protected DeviceAdmin mActivity;
    protected DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    protected ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
    protected boolean mAdminActive;

    // Optional shared UI
    private PreferenceScreen mSetPassword;
    private EditTextPreference mResetPassword;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Retrieve the useful instance variables
        mActivity = (DeviceAdmin) getActivity();
        mDPM = mActivity.mDPM;
        mDeviceAdminSample = mActivity.mDeviceAdminSample;
        mAdminActive = mActivity.isActiveAdmin();

        // Configure the shared UI elements (if they exist)
        mResetPassword = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(KEY_RESET_PASSWORD);
        mSetPassword = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference(KEY_SET_PASSWORD);

        if (mResetPassword != null) {
            mResetPassword.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }
        if (mSetPassword != null) {
            mSetPassword.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdminActive = mActivity.isActiveAdmin();
        reloadSummaries();
        // Resetting the password via API is available only to active admins
        if (mResetPassword != null) {
            mResetPassword.setEnabled(mAdminActive);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called automatically at every onResume.  Should also call explicitly any time a
     * policy changes that may affect other policy values.
     */
    protected void reloadSummaries() {
        if (mSetPassword != null) {
            if (mAdminActive) {
                // Show password-sufficient status under Set Password button
                boolean sufficient = mDPM.isActivePasswordSufficient();
                mSetPassword.setSummary(sufficient ?
                        R.string.password_sufficient : R.string.password_insufficient);
            } else {
                mSetPassword.setSummary(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        if (mSetPassword != null && preference == mSetPassword) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (mResetPassword != null && preference == mResetPassword) {
            doResetPassword((String)newValue);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This is dangerous, so we prevent automated tests from doing it, and we
     * remind the user after we do it.
     */
    private void doResetPassword(String newPassword) {
        if (alertIfMonkey(mActivity, R.string.monkey_reset_password)) {
            return;
        }
        mDPM.resetPassword(newPassword, DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        String message = mActivity.getString(R.string.reset_password_warning, newPassword);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_password_ok, null);
        builder.show();
    }

    /**
     * Simple helper for summaries showing local & global (aggregate) policy settings
     */
    protected String localGlobalSummary(Object local, Object global) {
        return getString(R.string.status_local_global, local, global);
    }
}

/**
 * PreferenceFragment for "general" preferences.
 */
public static class GeneralFragment extends AdminSampleFragment
        implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    // UI elements
    private CheckBoxPreference mEnableCheckbox;
    private CheckBoxPreference mDisableCameraCheckbox;
    private CheckBoxPreference mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox;
    private CheckBoxPreference mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.device_admin_general);
        mEnableCheckbox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(KEY_ENABLE_ADMIN);
        mEnableCheckbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mDisableCameraCheckbox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(KEY_DISABLE_CAMERA);
        mDisableCameraCheckbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox =
            (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(KEY_DISABLE_KEYGUARD_WIDGETS);
        mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox =
            (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(KEY_DISABLE_KEYGUARD_SECURE_CAMERA);
        mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    // At onResume time, reload UI with current values as required
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mEnableCheckbox.setChecked(mAdminActive);
        enableDeviceCapabilitiesArea(mAdminActive);

        if (mAdminActive) {
            mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, mDisableCameraCheckbox.isChecked());
            mDPM.setKeyguardDisabledFeatures(mDeviceAdminSample, createKeyguardDisabledFlag());
            reloadSummaries();
        }
    }

    int createKeyguardDisabledFlag() {
        int flags = DevicePolicyManager.KEYGUARD_DISABLE_FEATURES_NONE;
        flags |= mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox.isChecked() ?
                DevicePolicyManager.KEYGUARD_DISABLE_WIDGETS_ALL : 0;
        flags |= mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox.isChecked() ?
                DevicePolicyManager.KEYGUARD_DISABLE_SECURE_CAMERA : 0;
        return flags;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (super.onPreferenceChange(preference, newValue)) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;
        if (preference == mEnableCheckbox) {
            if (value != mAdminActive) {
                if (value) {
                    // Launch the activity to have the user enable our admin.
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                            mActivity.getString(R.string.add_admin_extra_app_text));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
                    // return false - don't update checkbox until we're really active
                    return false;
                } else {
                    mDPM.removeActiveAdmin(mDeviceAdminSample);
                    enableDeviceCapabilitiesArea(false);
                    mAdminActive = false;
                }
            }
        } else if (preference == mDisableCameraCheckbox) {
            mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, value);
            reloadSummaries();
        } else if (preference == mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox
                || preference == mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox) {
            mDPM.setKeyguardDisabledFeatures(mDeviceAdminSample, createKeyguardDisabledFlag());
            reloadSummaries();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void reloadSummaries() {
        super.reloadSummaries();
        String cameraSummary = getString(mDPM.getCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample)
                ? R.string.camera_disabled : R.string.camera_enabled);
        mDisableCameraCheckbox.setSummary(cameraSummary);

        int disabled = mDPM.getKeyguardDisabledFeatures(mDeviceAdminSample);

        String keyguardWidgetSummary = getString(
                (disabled & DevicePolicyManager.KEYGUARD_DISABLE_WIDGETS_ALL) != 0 ?
                        R.string.keyguard_widgets_disabled : R.string.keyguard_widgets_enabled);
        mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox.setSummary(keyguardWidgetSummary);

        String keyguardSecureCameraSummary = getString(
            (disabled & DevicePolicyManager.KEYGUARD_DISABLE_SECURE_CAMERA) != 0 ?
            R.string.keyguard_secure_camera_disabled : R.string.keyguard_secure_camera_enabled);
        mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox.setSummary(keyguardSecureCameraSummary);
    }

    /** Updates the device capabilities area (dis/enabling) as the admin is (de)activated */
    private void enableDeviceCapabilitiesArea(boolean enabled) {
        mDisableCameraCheckbox.setEnabled(enabled);
        mDisableKeyguardWidgetsCheckbox.setEnabled(enabled);
        mDisableKeyguardSecureCameraCheckbox.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main


05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.getKeyguardDisabledFeatures
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at com.example.deviceadmin.DeviceAdmin$GeneralFragment.reloadSummaries(DeviceAdmin.java:317)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at com.example.deviceadmin.DeviceAdmin$AdminSampleFragment.onResume(DeviceAdmin.java:159)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at com.example.deviceadmin.DeviceAdmin$GeneralFragment.onResume(DeviceAdmin.java:256)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1018)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1810)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4549)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2461)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2499)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-06 00:19:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9614):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help. ! I am not getting satisfactory answers from a long time for my questions :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the device in question support this?  What version of Android is it running?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have kept target as Jellybean ,it works on emulator for Jellybean ,My device is ICS, ICS supports DeviceAdmin API , Cant understand

Answer (score 2):

Although some of the Device Admin API was added earlier, the specific method [getKeyguardDisabledFeatures()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getKeyguardDisabledFeatures%28android.content.ComponentName%29) was only added in API 17, ie android Android 4.2 or JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and about the most recent version released as of this writting.

Therefore you will not be able to use that approach on your ICS test device, or many of those which users have in their hands as of May 2013.

Presumably your successful test was on an emulator running 4.2 or 4.2.2

Comment: So cant I disable camera on ICS ?! From where can I get Sample for API 14 (ICS) then ?

Comment: I am new to android development , Please guide,Thanks

Comment: The Android tool will let you install the samples for API 14, but I have no idea if those include a way to disable the camera.

Comment: Okay , thanks anyway :) If you come to know,please let me know